# Issue with sliding door CSS menu...

Tags: css, menu, navigation

So I'm trying to do a sliding door CSS menu -- basically one image that you move the background position on when it's hovered or when it's active.

However, usually when I move to the next link using:

```
#xmenu li.ypart {width:80px; height:35px;}
#xmenu li.ypart a {background-position:-33px 0px; }
```

It takes from the last link to whatever width I specify. See the MAP icon on the image below? I'm trying to link it so that the link doesn't go all the way from the SEND FEEDBACK link to the map button. I just want the link to be that square.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S70f.png]

So any ideas?

Comment: I see that this is a pretty old question, but for future reference, I wanted to point out that, while the question title refers to the [sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) technique, the text actually describes a [CSS sprite](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should make the link (the `<a>` element) a block element and give it a specific width and height (and maybe relative/absolute positioning, depending on how your layout is set up). That way, the hit area for the link will be confined to those dimensions.

Something like this for the markup:

```
...
<a href="/map">Map</a>
...
```

And something like this for the CSS:

```
#xmenu li.ypart a { display: block; width: 40px; height: 35px; }
```